# Error in SSIS DataSouce preview using Npgsql as ADO.NET Provider

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, npgsql

I'm using Npgsql 3.0.5 as ADO.NET DataSource Provider to move data from one DB to another with some transformations

I having an error when trying to PREVIEW data which:

> "57014: canceling statement due to user request (Npgsql)"

It is looks like "VS" just cancels query execution and returns error.

**Full Error description :**

> ===================================
>
> There was an error displaying the preview. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> ===================================
>
> 57014: canceling statement due to user request (Npgsql)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode
>   dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage, Boolean
>   isPrependedMessage)    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode
>   dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage)    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.SkipUntil(BackendMessageCode stopAt1,
>   BackendMessageCode stopAt2)    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.SkipUntil(BackendMessageCode stopAt1,
>   BackendMessageCode stopAt2)    at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Consume()
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Close()    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.ShowDataPreview(String
>   sqlStatement, DbConnection connection, Control parentWindow,
>   IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
>   IDTSExternalMetadataColumnCollection100 externalColumns)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.ShowDataPreview(String
>   sqlStatement, ConnectionManager connectionManager, Control
>   parentWindow, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
>   IDTSExternalMetadataColumnCollection100 externalColumns)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowConnectionPage.previewButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

Installed Npgsql from 
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.50730.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Can anyone help with that bug?